# sass how to change color for all links under a class?

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to change hover/active/visited color for all link `a` under this class, how to achieve this in sass?

```
.header-reset {
        margin-right: 40px;
    }
```

Comment: why  down votes?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but i'm assuming the lack of explanation what you have tried before posting this question. Or 'not working' code. You simply state a question with some css that isn't related to the question expect the class-name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
   .header-reset {
     margin-right:40px;
     a {
      &:visited {
        color: color-code/variable;
      }
      &:hover {
        color: color-code/variable;  
      }
      &:active {
        color: color-code/variable;
      }
    }
  }
```

this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
.header-reset {
        margin-right: 40px;
  a{
     &:hover{

     }
     &:active{

     }
     &:focus{

    }   
   }    
}
```